# Day Name from Date in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display the name of the day given a date (like "05/23/2014") which I get from a 3rd party.

I've tried using `Date`, but I only get the date.

What is the correct way to get the name of the day?

Comment: convert it to a date, then call `getDay()` to get the day number (0-6, 0==Sunday), and then use an array of the day names to map the number to the name.

Comment: // The days of the week are: "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
function getDayName(dateString) {
    let dayName = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][new Date(dateString).getDay()];
    return dayName;
}
let result = getDayName(10/12/2022);
console.log(result);

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You could use the `Date.getDay()` method, which returns 0 for sunday, up to 6 for saturday. So, you could simply create an array with the name for the day names:

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date(dateString);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
```

Here `dateString` is the string you received from the third party API.

Alternatively, if you want the first 3 letters of the day name, you could use the `Date` object's built-in `toString` method:

```
var d = new Date(dateString);
var dayName = d.toString().split(' ')[0];
```

That will take the first word in the `d.toString()` output, which will be the 3-letter day name.

Comment: This is probably NOT the best way to do it. The standard Javascript Date class provides ways to get the full name. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: But..."standard Javascript date class" doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @HernánEche according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date every single browser supports Date just fine. Which browser does it not work for you?

Comment: @Joeytje50 WebView from JavaFx, but ok, doesn't qualify as 'browser'

Comment: @HernánEche JavaFx, as far as I can find on the internet, is Java, not JavaScript. These languages are completely different, so you should try looking for things related to Java. See https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/faq/difference-between-java-and-javascript/ (or any other result on Google under "difference between java and javascript") for more information about that.

Comment: @Joeytje50 If you keep searching, you will "find on the internet" that Javascript can be run from Java too, with WebView objects and WebEngine you can load web pages, creates document models, css styles and runs JavaScript, you are welcome.

Comment: @HernánEche Okay, I was not aware of that. Regardless, I have never heard about that and I have no idea what kind of features are supported by it. If you have a solution for Java's WebView / WebEngine, feel free to post it either as a seperate answer below, or if you are not able to find it anywhere else, feel free to post a new question here on SO. For my answer, however, I can't really help you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Only about 1/3 of the world uses Sunday as the first day of the week, so this is just plain wrong for 2/3 of the world, including Europe: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:First_Day_of_Week_World_Map.svg

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Then I've got good news for you: Just call sunday the 7th day, take modulo 7, and you've got yourself exactly this list! Anyway, front-end users will never even see this array. The array is just a computer-readable list that converts this number into a string. I'm not sure what's wrong about my answer; if anything, `Date.getDay()` returning `0` for sunday would be the thing that is "wrong" for 2/3rds of the world then, right? I've just implemented something that deals with this fact. I never claimed sunday was the first day of the week... or the last day, for that matter.

Answer (score 321):

Use the [methods provided by the standard JavaScript Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

**Getting the day name from a date**:

```
function getDayName(dateStr, locale)
{
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });        
}

var dateStr = '05/23/2014';
var day = getDayName(dateStr, "nl-NL"); // Gives back 'Vrijdag' which is Dutch for Friday.
```

**Getting all weekdays in an array:**

```
function getWeekDays(locale)
{
    var baseDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2)); // just a Monday
    var weekDays = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {       
        weekDays.push(baseDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' }));
        baseDate.setDate(baseDate.getDate() + 1);       
    }
    return weekDays;
}

var weekDays = getWeekDays('nl-NL'); // Gives back { 'maandag', 'dinsdag', 'woensdag', 'donderdag', 'vrijdag', 'zaterdag', 'zondag'} which are the days of the week in Dutch.
```

For American dates use 'en-US' as locale.

Comment: I was not aware of this method existing at all at the time of posting my solution. Very nice solution indeed. It's also nice that this directly provides internationalisation. Also, it's nice to learn something new :P

Comment: A possible reason some people may not use it is because, according to the page you linked to, it seems there is not full compatibility with locales on mobile platforms.

Comment: @John Jun: True. Currently, most browsers on mobile devices support it. Most notable, the default Android browser does not. Chrome on Android does. (It is advised to use Chrome on Android anyway.. Different discussion.)

Comment: Only partially works in IE10. weekday is recognized but always returns the long name, even if I specify 'short'. 'short' does work in Chrome. Also IE10 doesn't recognize the 'month' keyword. It just returns a date, like 'Thu Jan 1 1970' when used with 'long', whereas Chrome does return the long month names.

Comment: Hmm, let me rephrase that. After some more fiddling, IE10 doesn't seem to bother with anything you specify, not even the locale. It always returns a full date with long names according to the OS locale.

Comment: I had to explicitly specify UTC timezone, or it would use my local timezone and give me the previous day: return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC' });

Comment: Hum… The date string you pass as an argument to the function is not normalized (ISO8601). Is the Dutch date format you are using here retrieved as a locale?

Comment: @Brice: Passing a date string in ISO8601 format (in the example '2014-05-23') works. See https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Comment: @RWC: It does — but "var dateStr = '05/23/2014';" yields no ISO8601 date. Now I understand that passing the locale as a second parameter will allow for date-format transformation to canonic ISO8601. Am I right?

Comment: There is no "Date class", there is a built–in Date constructor. The options for *toLocaleString* are part of ECMA-402, they aren't part of ECMAScript (i.e. "standard javascript"). [Support for toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility) is patchy, particularly for languages other than English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not work for some locales like `uz-Latn-UZ` in Chrome. Does anyone know how one could contribute to Chrome so that it is supported? Thanks

Comment: Just in case anybody wants to use it and could use a one-liner:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,0].map(i=>new Date(86400000*(i+3)).toLocaleDateString("de-DE", { weekday: 'long' }))`
will give you an array containing the names of the specificied locale (in this case de-DE and you can simply use the start array to specify the order of days. For example in this case the week starts on monday rather than sunday.

Answer (score 56):

use the Date.toLocaleString() method :

```
new Date(dateString).toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday:'long'})
```

Answer (score 31):

```
let weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][new Date().getDay()]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "...", //etc
    "Saturday"
];

console.log(days[new Date().getDay()]);
```

Simple, read the Date object in JavaScript manual

To do other things with date, like get a readable string from it, I use:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toLocaleString();
```

If you just want time or date use:

```
d.toLocaleTimeString();
d.toLocaleDateString();
```

You can parse dates either by doing:

```
var d = new Date(dateToParse);
```

or

```
var d = Date.parse(dateToParse);
```

Comment: days[Date.now().getDay() is wrong because Date.now() returns a number, not a Date.

Comment: it should be `days[new Date().getDay()]`

Answer (score 10):

To get the day from any given date, just pass the date into a new Date object:

```
let date = new Date("01/05/2020");
let day = date.toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday: 'long'});
console.log(day);
// expected result = tuesday
```

To read more, go to mdn-date.prototype.toLocaleString()(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 9):

```
let weekday = new Date(dateString).toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday:'long'});
console.log('Weekday',weekday);
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this :

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
// expected output: Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG', options));
// expected output: الخميس، ٢٠ ديسمبر، ٢٠١٢

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('ko-KR', options));
// expected output: 2012년 12월 20일 목요일
```

Source : [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 5):

One line solution :

```
let day = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"][new Date().getDay()]
```

Answer (score 4):

One more option is to use the inbuilt function [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), e.g.:

```js
const getDayName = (dateString) =>
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-Us', { weekday: 'long' }).format(new Date(dateString));
```

```html
<label for="inp">Enter a date string in the format "MM/DD/YYYY" or "YYYY-MM-DD" and press "OK":</label><br>
<input type="text" id="inp" value="01/31/2021">
<button onclick="alert(getDayName(document.getElementById('inp').value))">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and simplest way:

```
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var dayName = days[new Date().getDay()];
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var dayName =['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var day = dayName[new Date().getDay()];
console.log(day)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
var event = new Date();
var options = { weekday: 'long' };
console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

this will give you the day name in string format.

Comment: A [solution with *toLocaleString*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464959/257182) was posted 2 years earlier, why is this answer needed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of over-complicated solutions if anyone else comes up with something better, please let us know :)

```
any-name.js

var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long'
});
```

```
any-name.html
<script>
    document.write(today);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Shortest one liner**

Change the UTC day from 6 to 5 if you want Array to start from Sunday.

```js
const getWeekDays = (locale) => [...Array(7).keys()].map((v)=>new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 6+v)).toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' }));

console.log(getWeekDays('de-DE'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This method doesn't require you to set a random date or know the stringLocale beforehand. This method is independent from predefined values.
The locale can be retrieved from the client.

Automatically fill the weekdays array in the string locale.

```js
const locale = 'en-US' // Change this based on client settings
const date = new Date()

const weekdays = []
while(!weekdays[date.getDay()]) {
  weekdays[date.getDay()] = date.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: 'long'})
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
}

console.log(weekdays)
```

If you want the locale names for the months as well;

```js
const locale = 'en-US' // Change this based on client settings
const date = new Date()
date.setMonth(0) // Not strictly needed, but why not..
date.setDate(1) // Needed because if current date is >= 29, the month Feb can get skipped.

const months = []
while(!months[date.getMonth()]) {
  months[date.getMonth()] = date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long'})
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
}

console.log(months)
```

I currently use it like this:
(As you can see, I make a clone of the current date and set the month and date to their first occurance)

```js
const date = new Date()

let locale = navigator.languages
    ? navigator.languages[0]
    : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
let clone = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

let weekdays = []
while (!weekdays[clone.getDay()]) {
  weekdays[clone.getDay()] = {
    index: clone.getDay(),
    long: clone.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: 'long' }),
    short: clone.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: 'short' })
  }
  clone.setDate(clone.getDate() + 1)
}
clone.setDate(clone.getDate() - weekdays.length) // Reset

let months = []
while (!months[clone.getMonth()]) {
    months[clone.getMonth()] = {
        index: clone.getMonth(),
        long: clone.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long' }),
        short: clone.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'short' })
    }
    clone.setMonth(clone.getMonth() + 1)
}
clone.setMonth(clone.getMonth() - months.length) // Reset

let hours = []
while (!hours[clone.getHours()]) {
    hours[clone.getHours()] = {
        index: clone.getHours(),
        hour24: clone.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }),
        hour12: clone.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour12: true, hour: 'numeric' })
    }
    clone.setHours(clone.getHours() + 1)
}
clone.setHours(clone.getHours() - hours.length) // Reset

console.log(locale)
console.log(weekdays)
console.log(months)
console.log(hours)
console.log(clone.toLocaleString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution No.1

```
var today = new Date();

  var day = today.getDay();

  var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

  var dayname = days[day];

  document.write(dayname);
```

Solution No.2

```
      var today = new Date();

  var day = today.getDay();

  switch(day){
    case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;

    case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;

    case 2:
    day ="Tuesday";
    break;

    case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;

    case 4:
    day = "Thrusday";
    break;

    case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;

    case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
    break;
  }


document.write(day);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious from posts here or the msn/mozilla documentation but if you want to do this for the user's current Locale settings then use the following:

```
date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { weekday: 'long'});
```

"null" doesn't work as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

using toLocalDateString

```js
const date = new Date();
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-us', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an object

```
var days = {
   'Mon': 'Monday',
   'etc..': 'etc..',
   'Fri': 'Friday'
}

var date = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0]; //get day abreviation first
console.log(days[date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it:

```js
function getWeekDayNames(format = 'short', locale = 'ru') {
  const names = [];
  const date = new Date('2020-05-24');
  let days = 7;

  while (days !== 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    names.push(date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: format }));
    days--;
  }

  return names;
}
```

About formats you can read here [Documentation DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// request a weekday along with a long date
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
// → "Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012"

// an application may want to use UTC and make that visible
options.timeZone = 'UTC';
options.timeZoneName = 'short';
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
// → "Thursday, December 20, 2012, UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

// Solve this problem with a function.
// The days of the week are: "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"

```
function getDayName(dateString) {
   let dayName = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][new Date(dateString).getDay()];
        return dayName;
    }
    let result = getDayName(10/12/2022);
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: `getDayName(10/12/2022);` isn't passing a string value, just the result of the mathematical operation `10/12/2022`

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocaleString` method with options. Also here is way to get list of weekday names dynamically for given locale.

```js
const weekdayNames = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => {
    d = new Date(i * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return [d.getDay(), d.toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })];
  })
);

// Full week day for given date string
console.log(weekdayNames[new Date("2023/07/31").getDay()]);

// Get list of week day full names
console.log(Object.values(weekdayNames));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var today = new Date();

var currentDay = today.getDay();

switch (currentDay) {
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday"
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday"
    break;
  case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
    break;
  default:
    day = "one day forever "
    break;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't an array be easier than `switch/case`?

Comment: Wouldn't parsing and formatting the date using `toLocaleString()` be even easier?

Answer (score -3):

**Not the best method, use an array instead. This is just an alternative method.**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
```

You should really use google before you post here.

Since other people posted the array method I'll show you an alternative way using a switch statement.

```
switch(day) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;

    ... rest of cases

    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

The above works, however, the array is the better alternative. You may also use `if()` statements however a switch statement would be much cleaner then several if's.

Comment: This will return an numeric value from 0-6 -- not the day of the week.

Comment: You can handle it from there and convert it to a day.

Comment: That is true. I'm just letting you know that this doesn't answer OP's question as-written.

Comment: A `switch`? Why would you use a `switch` instead of a simple `Array`? I mean, I guess it is an alternative to the other answers... But holy writing time, Batman... :/

Comment: Because why post the same thing as 2 other people?

Comment: W3Schools is not a respected source