# How to display weekday name of the current day using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the display today days using gate 
but no idea about to start in *TypeScript*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js)

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. You can use almost any JavaScript within TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment pointed out, TypeScript is also JavaScript. So you can:

```
const now = new Date();
day = now.getDay();
// Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Get current weekday. just like @libo but inline

```
new Date().getDay();
```