# Can anyone tell me how this javaScript function works please?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am a beginner and recently I have stumbled onto this. I do not understand what this `d.getDays()` does. Please help me out.

```js
const dateBuilder = (d) => {
  let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

  let day = days[d.getDay()];
  let date = d.getDate();
  let month = months[d.getMonth()];
  let year = d.getFullYear();

  return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
}
console.log(dateBuilder(new Date()));
```

Comment: The [**getDay()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

Comment: @JackBashford I've mentioned this many times before. Please don't add unrelated tags to earn badges. The ecmascript-6 tag wiki clearly says *"Only use this tag where the question specifically relates to new features or technical changes provided in ECMAScript 2015*".  The question is about simple bracket notation.

Comment: For more details, please check [Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24998624) and [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643320)

Comment: Apologies @adiga - I was looking at the wrong area. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's a method of the `Date` object that returns a number representing the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc.) that correlates to the `days` array you have in your code. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay). It's basically getting the "name" of the day by using that array `days`:

```
let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that d is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

[getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) is a method being called on that object.