# I'd like the day of week to display as name instead of a number

Tags: javascript

```
function compute(event){<br>
    console.log(event);<br>

    event.preventDefault();<br>


    var form=new FormData(event.target);<br>
    var day=form.get("day");<br>
    var month=form.get("month");<br>
    var year=form.get("year");<br>
    var gender=form.get("gender");<br>
    var names= {
        Sunday: {
        male: 'Kwasi',
        female: 'Akosua'
        },
        Monday: {
        male: 'Kwadwo',
        female: 'Adwoa'
        },
        Tuesday: {
        male: 'Kwabena',
        female: 'Abenaa'
        },
        Wednesday: {
        male: 'Kwaku',
        female: 'Akua'
        },
        Thursday: {
        male: 'Yaw',
        female: 'Yaa'
        },
        Friday: {
        male: 'Kofi',
        female: 'Afua'
        },
        Saturday: {
        male: 'Kwame',
        female: 'Ama'
        },
        } <br>
    var date=[year,month,day].join("/");<br>
    var day = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];<br>
    var d = new Date(dateString);<br>
    var dayName = days[d.getDay()];<br>
    var date=new Date(date);<br>
    console.log(date);<br>

    var dayOfweekBorn=date.getDay();<br>
    console.log(dayOfweekBorn);<br>

    var daysOfTheWeek=Object.keys(names);<br>
    var ghanaNames=names[daysOfTheWeek[dayOfweekBorn]][gender];<br>
    console.log(ghanaNames);<br>
    
}
```

Comment: checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js

Comment: How are you not getting any errors with all those `<br>`s?  
They are HTML elements, not javascript...

Comment: I think you meant: `var dateString=[year,month,day].join("/");` instead of `var date=...`, otherwise:
You are setting `date` - `var date=[year,month,day].join("/");`,  
Not using it,  
Then re-setting it 4 lines later - `var date=new Date(date)` - AND re-"`var`"ing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes in the number of the day (0 = sunday) and return the day of the week. You can use a switch statement for this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: `toLocaleString("en",{weekday:"long"})` returns "Sunday", "Monday", etc.

Assuming the input is correct and in the format as in the following function descriptive parameters, you can try:

```
function ghanaName(yearString, monthString, dayOfMonthString, fullLowerCaseGender) {
  var names={
    Sunday:   {male:'Kwasi',   female: 'Akosua'},
    Monday:   {male:'Kwadwo',  female: 'Adwoa' },
    Tuesday:  {male:'Kwabena', female: 'Abenaa'},
    Wednesday:{male:'Kwaku',   female: 'Akua'  },
    Thursday: {male:'Yaw',     female: 'Yaa'   },
    Friday:   {male:'Kofi',    female: 'Afua'  },
    Saturday: {male:'Kwame',   female: 'Ama'   }
  }
  var dateFromString=new Date(yearString+"/"+monthString+"/"+dayOfMonthString);
  var dayOfWeek=dateFromString.toLocaleString("en",{weekday:"long"});
  return names[dayOfWeek][fullLowerCaseGender];
}
```

to be used, for example:

```
ghanaName("2020","07","19","male")
```

Your use of `names` object is excellent!

Comment: So, is my answer good/working for you?  If so, please select it.