# How can i display a paragraph when today is the weekday i want

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello Stackoverflow community, I want to use JavaScript to display a paragraph when today is Wednesday. I have already tried but have not managed to do it

I already tried this:

```
var weekday = Wednesday.getDay();
var options = { weekday: 'long'};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(Wednesday));

if (Date.prototype.getDay() = 2) {
 answer = "yes it is wednesday"
} else {
 answer = "it isn't wednesday"
}
$("#output").html(answer);
```

Now I don't know what to do because I am a beginner with JavaScript and HTML

Comment: Is this a  jQuery question? If so, please add the `jQuery` tag to your post :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
[Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js)

Ps:

```
Date.prototype.getDay() = 2)
```

`= 2` is assign value operator not to compare...

[JavaScript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

```js
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date();
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];

dayName != "Wednesday" ? document.body.innerHTML = "Not Wednesday" : document.body.innerHTML = dayName
```

*reported as duplicate*

Comment: and how can i use css to edit the output?