# How to get current week days javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to get current weekdays

Let's say Today is 29 Wednesday (29 day and Wednesday Week)

How do I get this

*26 Sunday

*27 Monday

*28 Tuesday

*29 Wednesday

30 Thursday

31 Friday

1 Saturday

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Day Name from Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show what you have done so far and where you do struggle at?

Comment: If you show your code, I can answer base on your code.

Comment: But I also want the date.

Comment: I always recommend using momentjs or luxon as they handle the special cases

Answer (score 3):

```js
const name = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
const now = Date.now();
const DAY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
const today = new Date(now).getDay();

for (let i = today; i >= 0; i--) {
  const date = new Date(now - DAY * i);
  console.log("*",name[date.getDay()], date.getDate());
}
for (let i = 1; i < 7 - today; i++) {
  const date = new Date(now + DAY * i);
  console.log(name[date.getDay()], date.getDate());
}
```

Comment: can you explain why it start from 26 where it should start from today which is 29

Comment: @MustafaJawadAbdullaSarhan today is 29 but the first day of this week is 26.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for on a Date object is getDay(). It returns a number between 0 and 6 (where 0 is Sunday). You could create an array of day names and use the getDay function to fetch the name from it. E.g.

```
const dayNames = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursdsay',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
];

// get todays date
const today = new Date();
return dayNames(today.getDay());
```

You can read more about the getDay function [on the MDN web docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) and [the Date object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Similarly getDate() returns the date of the Date object.