# Create array with day names of the week to numbers

Tags: javascript, html

How to get first day name of month and output the day name of a specific date?
Example: *first day name of month: Wednesday specific date*

```js
var a;
var b;
var x;
var y;

function f() {
  name();
  date();
  result();
}

function name() {
  a = Number(document.getElementById("name").value);
  if (a == "") {
    document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = " put the first day!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function date() {
  b = Number(document.getElementById("date").value);
  if (b == "") {
    document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = "  put your specific date !";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function result() {
  y = (b - 1) + a;
  if (b > 8) {
    x = y % 7;
    document.getElementById('result').value = x;
  } else if (y >= 7) {
    x = y - 7;
    document.getElementById('result').value = x;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="warpper">
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" placeholder="" id="name">
        <br>
        <span id="demo1"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" placeholder="" id="date">
        <br>
        <span id="demo2"></span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="f()">do it</button>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" placeholder="result" id="result">
        <br>
        <span id="demo3"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998624/day-name-from-date-in-js

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The script has to be INSIDE the head tags. I made you a [mcve]

Comment: I recommend to do `if (a === 0)` instead of `a == ""` since you should not rely on JS casting your variables to something unintuitive. Alternatively test the value is empty before converting it to a number

Answer (score 0):

- I have two input fields: one for the month and one for the day.
- The **calculate()** function is called when the user clicks the
  "Calculate" button. It retrieves the values from the input fields,
  validates them, calculates the day name of the first day of the month
  and the day name of the specific date, and then displays the results
  in the output box.

This setup allows you to input both the month and the day and get the desired output accordingly.

```js
function calculate() {
  var month = Number(document.getElementById("month").value);
  var day = Number(document.getElementById("day").value);

  // Check if month and day are valid
  if (isNaN(month) || isNaN(day) || month < 1 || month > 12 || day < 1 || day > 31) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Invalid input";
    return;
  }

  var year = new Date().getFullYear(); // Get the current year
  var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 1).getDay(); // Get the day of the week for the first day of the month (0-6)
  var dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var firstDayNameOfMonth = dayNames[firstDayOfMonth];

  var specificDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // Create a Date object for the specific date
  var specificDayName = dayNames[specificDate.getDay()]; // Get the day name of the specific date

  // Display the results
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "First day name of month: " + firstDayNameOfMonth + "<br>" +
    "Day name of specific date: " + specificDayName;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="warpper">
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Month (1-12)" id="month" min="1" max="12">
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Day" id="day" min="1" max="31">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <div class="output-box">
      <p id="output"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [ChatGPT generated answers are banned at SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) - this is clearly said in the editor when you click answer